# Laravel Auth, Passing user credentials to Notification Class after registering

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-authentication, laravel-mail, laravel-notification

I am trying to pass User details to my notification so I can say:
Dear User name, but couldnt figure it how. Also, I am looking forward to getting the default URL when verifying the user. So, basically I only wanted to change the first ->line() in my toMail function.

**In User Model:**

```
public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
{
    $this->notify(new CustomVerifyEmail($this->user));
}
```

**In CustomVerifyEmail Class**

```
public $user;
    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->line('The introduction to the notification.'.$this->user->email)
                    ->action('Notification Action', url('/'))
                    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get the 'name' from the `$notifiable` that is passed to the `toMail` call, assuming it will be your `User` model:

```
line('The introduction to the notification.'. $notifiable->name)
```

---

For ways to customize the `MailMessage` that is sent I have added an answer to your other question. [Laravel Auth, Getting the default URL that is passed in Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58897705/2109233)