# Laravel Auth, Getting the default URL that is passed in Notification

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-authentication, laravel-notification, laravel-6.2

I just wanted to change the ->greeting() in notification in my toMail() function of the default auth after registering. I want to retain the verify URL and etc. But I am stucked. If I override the sendEmailVerificationnotification() the whole mail is changed. How to get the URL that was supposed to be sent originally or how to edit the original auth to edit only the ->greeting('Hello') with Dear Name, ?

**In User Model**

```
public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
{
    $this->notify(new CustomVerifyEmail());
}
```

**In CustomVerifyEmail**

```
/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail'];
}

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    //dd($notifiable);
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->greeting('Dear ' . $notifiable->name . ',')
                ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
                ->action('Notification Action', url())
                ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}

/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        //
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to be able to customize the `MailMessage` that is sent by `VerifyEmail` without overriding any methods or writing your own Notification class.

The `Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail` class will actually let you assign your own callback for handling the `toMail` side of the Notification. This callback receives the `$notifiable` and the `$verificationUrl`. You could try something like this:

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage; 

VerifyEmail::$toMailCallback = function ($notifiable, $verificationUrl) {
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->greeting("Dear {$notifiable->name},")
        ->line('The introduction to the notification.')
        ->action('Notification Action', $verificationUrl)
        ->line('Thank you for using our application!');        
};
```

You could put that in a Service Provider's `boot` method.

---

If you didn't want to go that way you could extend the `VerifyEmail` Notification to write your own `toMail` method, but have access to the functionality to get the verification URL.

```
use Illuminate\Auth\Notifications\VerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage; 

class CustomVerifyEmail extends VerifyEmail
{
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $verificationUrl = $this->verificationUrl($notifiable);

        return (new MailMessage)
            ...
    }
}
```

Then override the `sendEmailVerificationNotification` on the User Model to send the custom notification, like you have done already.

Comment: thank you very much @lagbox. I will this an answer soon.

Comment: it is fine. this answer belongs to this thread. I've been looking at other's answers but none of them is as complete as what you have stated. Others lacks the imports (use) so I couldnt make heads or tail but this one is really perfect. Thanks again ! :D